# looping over an array and checking its elements

Tags: julia

I have an array 'A'. I want to do a loop over all the elements of A, checking to see if any are greater than or equal to 1. If they are, I would like to assign a '1' to a new array 'B' in the same element index of A.

How would I go about implementing this?

I have the cumbersome idea of:

```
for i in 1:end
for j in 1:end
if A[i,j] >= 1
B[i,j] = 1
else
B[i,j] = 0
end
end
end
```

but I would prefer something more succinct.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: My apologies. I have added an attempt in my code to show my intentions; I'm just looking for a more compact way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly use broadcasting as Oscar suggested (e.g. `B = A .>= 1`), but there's also nothing wrong with loops, since loops are fast and avoid excess allocations. You really only need one loop though, and the if statement is slightly superfluous, so:

```
B = similar(A, Int64) # If B doesn't already exist, otherwise omit this line
@inbounds for i in eachindex(A)
    B[i] = A[i] >= 1
end
```

The `@inbounds` is optional, but improves speed.

Answer (score 4):

Just use broadcast:

```
B = A .≥ 1
```

Comment: Or actually just `B = A .>= 1` (don't need the indices when broadcasting)

Comment: Note that this will create a `BitVector`. If `B` already exists, then `B .= (A .>= 1)` will retain the correct element type.